Replace Wayland with Xorg
I am a bit of a linux newbie so please have mercy on me:
I found out that remmina does not work well with wayland (in a multimonitor setup) I do however need this multimonitor support. So i would like to replace wayland with xorg.
Thank you!

you can use remmina as flatpak, install flatseal and then turn on the flag "fallback to X11 Window System".  I am using it for quite sometimes now and it works like a charm
